# What is a "senior" tongue depressor?

Tags: home-medical-equipment

Shopping for tongue depressors online, I found some that were listed as "senior".  What is the difference between a "senior" tongue depressor and an "adult" one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the products online labelled as such, **there seems to be no difference between "adult size", "Standard" and "Senior" sized (6") tongue depressors**. On the other hand, I would assume "Senior" is used to differentiat that product from the "Junior" (5.5"), "Infant" (4.5") tongue depressors, which some companies label as such.

Source:
http://www.puritanmedproducts.com/products?cat=1085%261076&search=&brand=&sterile=&material=